# Testing program for Branch Predictor in Java Have odd result

Tags: java, branch-prediction

I read the question [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) today and trying to replicate the result in Java.

Here's my code:

```
public class BranchPredictorTest {
    static int[] getBranchCounts1(List<Integer> list) {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] counts = new int[3];
        for(Integer v : list)
            if(v < 1000)
                counts[0]++;
            else if(v < 2000)
                counts[1]++;
            else 
                counts[2]++;
        System.out.println("[time cost]\t" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) + " ms");
        return counts;
    }

    static int[] getBranchCounts2(List<Integer> list) {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] counts = new int[3];
        for(Integer v : list)
            counts[v/1000]++;
        System.out.println("[time cost]\t" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) + " ms");
        return counts;
    }

    static void test(List<Integer> list) {
        int[] bc1 = getBranchCounts1(list);
        System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d, %d", bc1[0], bc1[1], bc1[2]));

        int[] bc2 = getBranchCounts2(list);
        System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d, %d", bc2[0], bc2[1], bc2[2]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<2e7; i++) {
            list.add(rand.nextInt(3000));
        }
        test(list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        test(list);
    }
}
```

You can see the 1st function is implemented with branches and the 2nd without branches. I ran both functions for sorted and unsorted array. Based on what I read for Branch Prediction, I expected the time cost to be:

sorted branch < sorted un-branch < unsorted un-branch < unsorted branch

But the result is a bit strange:

```
[time cost] 145 ms
6670864, 6671007, 6658129
[time cost] 65 ms
6670864, 6671007, 6658129
[time cost] 332 ms
6670864, 6671007, 6658129
[time cost] 1852 ms
6670864, 6671007, 6658129
```

The sorted branching time cost is larger than the unsorted ones, and after sorted the arraylist, the time cost of un-branch counting increased its runtime dramatically...

EDIT:
I tried the same logic in C++, and the result basically meets the expectation:

```
[time cost] 248 ms
[time cost] 142 ms
[time cost] 87 ms
[time cost] 143 ms
```

I hope anyone can give me an explanation of how that happens, thanks for viewing/answering my question.

Comment: Microbenchmarking is hard. Have you tried this with JMH?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the (odd) results you are seeing are due to the fact that you are running them without warming up the JVM.

Try running the above in a loop of say 1,000+ cycles and look at the 95 percentile or so.